# How to merge two descending order linked list into one ascending order linked list recursively?

Tags: java, merge, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have no idea, how to start this program in Java. I have a feeling I have to create a dummy head, and play around with it. If someone could provide an algorithm to solve it or a general direction, that would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Could you provide an example with numbers on how your linked lists would be and how the output should be after merging?

Comment: L1: 5 -> 4 -> 2-> null L2: 4 -> 2 ->1 -> -1 ->NULL FINAL: 5->4->-2->1-> -1

Comment: @crazyCats Provide further details as thoughtful edits to your Question, not as a Comment.

Comment: If this is schoolwork assignment, say so. That affects the solution offered.

Comment: I wasnt given more than these assumptions. Its a personal project I was working on.

Comment: @crazyCats in your example FINAL result is also ordered descending, is that the desired result? Should it be like FINAL: -1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5?